# LibGdx (OpenGl ES/Android) - Calling Texture.createGLHandle multiple times returns textureid of newly created texture overwriting it

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, libgdx

Android 2.1 - Eclipse

What steps will reproduce the problem?

**1.**

```
Create new Texture(managed) using new Texture(FileHandle, Format, bool);
 - glGenTextures is called
 - glHandle is created (Logcat: 100271) "bg_plainred.png"
 - uploadImageData calls glBindTexture(100271)

Create new Texture(managed) using new Texture(FileHandle, Format, bool);
 - glGenTextures is called
 - glHandle is created (Logcat: 315638026) "body2.png"
 - uploadImageData calls glBindTexture(315638026)
```

At this point, all textured sprites render correctly..

**2.**

```
Call Texture.dispose(); "bg_plainred.png"
 - glDeleteTextures(glHandle) (Logcat: glHandle = 100271)
```

**3.**

```
Create new Texture(managed) using new Texture(FileHandle, Format, bool);
 - glGenTextures is called
 - glHandle is created (Logcat: 100271) "bg_wallpaper.png"
 - uploadImageData calls glBindTexture(100271)


Create new Texture(managed) using new Texture(FileHandle, Format, bool);
 - glGenTextures is called
 - glHandle is created (Logcat: 100271) "clothes.png"
 - uploadImageData calls glBindTexture(100271)
```

So essentially, createGLHandle() returns 100271 twice essentially overwriting bg_wallpaper.png with clothes.png. If I try to reference the "bg_wallpaper" Texture in a Sprite, it obviously writes from "clothes.png".

If I force context loss and refocus, all textures are correct due to Textures being reloaded (managed) by Gdx.

[opengl.org/glGenTextures](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGenTextures.xml) states:

> glGenTextures returns n texture names in textures. There is no
>   guarantee that the names form a contiguous set of integers; however,
>   it is guaranteed that none of the returned names was in use
>   immediately before the call to glGenTextures.

My question is if there is anything I can call in GL that would force the texture to be 'in use' and not return the same glHandle id twice?

I'm not sure that this is a bug that I should submit to libgdx issues?

Texture.java code can be referenced here for further clarification:

[code.google.com/gdx/src/Texture.java](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/source/browse/trunk/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Texture.java)

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you asked here? http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=11

Comment: Done! Thanks, didn't realize that was there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identified the issue:

I was calling Texture.dispose() from outside the Screen.update() or Screen.render() methods which resulted in this error:

call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)

Switching the code to be executed from Screen.update solved the problem.